# Autofac выдает ошибку NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, di, autofac

Имеется класс:

```
 public class FileRepository : IFileRepository
 {
      private readonly string _connectionString;
      private readonly IUserStore _usersRepository;

      public FileRepository(string connectionString, IUserStore user)
      {     
           _connectionString = connectionString;      
           _usersRepository = user;
      }
      public void GetInfo()
      {
          _usersRepository.Get();
      }
 }
```

Второй класс:

```
 public class ShareRepository : IShareRepository
 {
      private readonly string _connectionString;
      private readonly IFileRepository _fileRepository;

      public ShareRepository(string connectionString, IFileRepository 
             fileRepository)
      {
           _connectionString = connectionString;
           _fileRepository = fileRepository;
      }

      public void GetTest()
      {
           _fileRepository.GetInfo()
      }          
 }
```

При выполнении `_fileRepository.GetInfo()` вызывается метод `GetInfo()` из класса `FileRepository`, который в свою очередь тоже использует DI и выполняет 
`_usersRepository.Get()` и здесь возникает ошибка:

```
  System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
```

Мой Autofac config:

```
  var connectionString = "......."

  builder.Register(ctx => new FileRepository(connectionString, new 
      UserRepository(connectionString)))
            .As<IFileRepository>();

  builder.Register(ctx => new ShareRepository(connectionString,
       new FileRepository(connectionString))).As<IShareRepository>();
```

Дополнение:

```
 builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserStore>.InstancePerRequest()
```

Comment: а IUserStore у вас в контейнере на что замаплен?

Comment: @PashaPash дополнил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше, если не вы будете создавать объекты вручную, а DI-контейнер будет создавать их за вас:

```
builder.Register(ctx => new ShareRepository(connectionString,
   new FileRepository(connectionString))).As<IShareRepository>();
```

Вот здесь вы создали `ShareRepository` вручную и ему передали вручную же созданный вами `FileRepository` без второго параметра. Подозреваю, у вас там `= null` примостилось где-то в конструкторе, поэтому `userRepository` и равен `null`.

Что нужно сделать — зарегистрировать соответствие типов и интерфейсов:

```
builder.RegisterType<FileRepositorty>()
       .As<IFileRepository>();

builder.RegisterType<ShareRepository>()
       .As<IShareRepository>();
```

Если хотите указать `connectionString` в качестве параметра, используйте метод[`WithParameter`](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html).